# Use of uninitialized variable warning

Tags: perl, unix, warnings, strict

I am using GetOptions to get values from perl

```
GetOptions(
       'lines=s'=>\$globallines,
        );
```

Here, `lines` is an optional argument. When the user does not enter a value, I am getting a `use of uninitialized variable` warning where I am using the `lines` variable in an if statement. I am unable to fix this warning. Can you please help him?

Sorry if it is a silly question,I am new to perl.

```
if($globallines>0){#<SOME CODEEE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is - if there's no argument supplied, the value is undefined. (not zero).

So comparing it numerically gives an error.

There's a few possible solutions, but the easiest is:

```
if ( $globallines and $globallines > 0 ) {
```

Or perhaps just initialise it if undefined:

```
$globallines //= 0; #sets it to zero if undef.
```

Comment: Can I use <$globallines //= "name";> for a string value also??

Comment: Er. Yes. I think. But it's not `<` for code quotes, but backticks. But perl doesn't care. You can assign using `$globallines //= "a name here";` just the same as a numeric value. But your `>0` test will error still if you do this. (Unless the string is `"0.0"` or otherwise numerically convertible to zero)

Answer (score 1):

If the `-lines` option is... er... optional(!), what do you want the behaviour to be when the option is omitted? Choose a default value and assign that before calling `GetOptions()`.

```
my $globallines = 0; # Or whatever value is appropriate

GetOptions(
   'lines=s' => \$globallines,
);
```

Also, don't you want `lines=i` rather than `lines=s`? That will ensure you only get an integer.